# VBA code to rename a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code which generate a set of outputs. After the output is generated we want to rename the sheet by taking value from two cells namely D5 and D6.

D5 value is `Wednesday`
D6 value is `September 13, 2017`

Name format for sheet: `wed 09-13`

Please help.

Comment: You haven't tried `LCase(Format(Range("D6").Value,"ddd mm-dd"))`?

Comment: I dont know to use it... am new to vba

Comment: For selecting a single cell i got Activesheet.name=Range("B5") ... but i want column B6 value also in the format i specified... any help will be appreciated

Comment: @NikhilThomas see my answer and code below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameActiveSheet()

Dim ShtName As String

With ActiveSheet
    ShtName = Left(.Range("D5").Value2, 3) & " " & Format(.Range("D6").Value, "mm-dd")
    .Name = ShtName
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error as "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: @NikhilThomas when you run the code in debug mode (press **F8**) at which line are you getting this error ?

Comment: @NikhilThomas Try closing Excel and restarting, start from scratch, and paste this code in a "clean" workbook, with judt the data in "D5" and "D6"

Comment: It was an error from my side.... i pasted in wrong column...  its working perfect. Thanks a lot Shai

Answer (score 0):

Since no relation on how Worksheets are to be renamed based on your Output, I will just show you key components to do so.

Below will rename *every* worksheet based on a date value in **D6** of each one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SO46440400()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    ' Assuming rename each sheet based on a cell value (D6) on that sheet:
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        oWS.Name = LCase(Format(DateValue(oWS.Range("D6").Value), "ddd mm-dd"))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I hv only one sub function.. if i need to make this change at last before End Sub how to modify it